# What happened after an upgrade to Catalina

Tags: catalina, software-update, stickies

I recently updated my Mac to Catalina. After the update the screen I used to swipe to the left that held my Sticky notes is not there. I would like to recover them as they had information on them I need. Where is that screen now, and if it's permanently gone is there a way to at least get the Sticky notes back? It was the same screen as the calculator, and other widgets.

Answer (score 11):

The widgets feature is known as "Dashboard", and was retired with macOS Catalina. The screen with the notes, calculator, etc. is gone.

You can access your sticky notes by opening the app Stickies. All your notes should have been imported there.

Comment: Or an even better way to launch Stickies: Cmd + Shift + Y

Comment: How do you do this? @MCCCS

Comment: Choose some text and press the keys then it'll open Stickies with that text.